# Prefixing variable assignment doesn't work with echo

Tags: bash

As far as I know, if you prefix a bash command with variable assignment the variable will take effect immediately. And it will only have effect within that command.

I tried this command in bash:

```
V=1 echo $V
```

However 1 is not printed out in the terminal which is not what I expected. So why it doesn't work?

Comment: See here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126938/why-is-setting-a-variable-before-a-command-legal-in-bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable will be passed in the environment of the command following it, not when the command is being evaluated (expanded). Any variable expansion will be done earlier by shell.

```
$ V=1 env | grep V=
V=1
```

To get it working:

```
$ V=1; echo $V
1
```

Comment: Actually: `V=1 eval echo \$V` also work as it is delaying the expansion of the variable `V` until after it is set in the environment. Without a permanent change that a semicolon (;) will cause, of course.

Comment: @BinaryZebra It definitely would but it's a lazy evaluation with some trick involved..should be avoided in most cases..

Comment: I meant no "trick". Just a explicit demonstration of delayed evaluation. Yes, I agree that it should be avoided in "production code". But it is invaluable as a learning tool.