# Bash: inject variable in command, that sets an env variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables

With bash, I'm trying to set environment variables for a given command by injecting another variable before running said command:

It's easier to describe that with an example:

```
setHELLO="HELLO=42"
${setHELLO} echo ${HELLO}
```

I would expect this script to output `42`, instead I get an error `line 2: HELLO=42: command not found`

Precision:
While here I could simply write

```
HELLO=42
echo ${HELLO}
```

I'm aiming to not provide all env variables to all commands in my shell script, which is why I'm setting the env variable explicitly right in the line where I run the command (`echo ${HELLO}`)

I'm also aiming to not repeat the variable value declaration, by not re-declaring in front of each command like this:

```
HELLO=42; echo command1
HELLO=42; echo command2
HELLO=42; echo command3
```

Comment: You can not expect `HELLO=42 echo ${HELLO}` to print 42. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36380569/prefixing-variable-assignment-doesnt-work-with-echo). Does this invalidate the question?

Comment: @thatotherguy It invalidates what I thought I knew, but brings more questions ! I fixed the last code block to be what I intended

Comment: Also, about the duplicates, while both useful, the first one has the declaration directly in-line rather than as a variable itself, and the second one is global. Can we keep this question as the answer is more complete and helpful in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semicolon in there and you're good. If you want to not corrupt local variables in your script env, use a function or use a subshell

## Semi-Colon

```sh
HELLO=69
setHELLO='let HELLO=42'
( ${setHELLO}; echo ${HELLO} ) # 42
( ${setHELLO}; echo ${HELLO} ) # 42
( ${setHELLO}; echo ${HELLO} ) # 42
echo $HELLO                    # 69
```

## Function

```sh
sayHello() {
    local HELLO=42
    echo ${HELLO}   # 42
    echo ${HELLO}   # 42
    echo ${HELLO}   # 42
}

HELLO=69
sayHello      # 42, 42, 42
echo ${HELLO} # 69
```

## Sourced bash script

```sh
#---------------
# This script is called sayHello.sh
echo $HELLO
#---------------

# From some other script/cmdline
HELLO=69
setHELLO='HELLO=42'
${setHELLO} source sayHello.sh  # 42
${setHELLO} source sayHello.sh  # 42
${setHELLO} source sayHello.sh  # 42
echo $HELLO                     # 69
```